# Does Spring have Jackson built in - If so how to parse JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I've creating a Spring Boot application. I've been told, Spring comes with Jackson - however every tutorial I'm seeing, shows adding it as a dependency.

I want to parse and create some JSON - is there a clear guide on how to do this - with using whatever is in Spring?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show your exact need with some pseudo code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a JSON response endpoint , all you need to do is create a rest endpoint that returns json. Springboot automatically configures jackson message converters for rest endpoints if it finds jackson as dependency or classpath.So all you need to enable a rest endpoint to return a json response is to have the jackson as dependency and springboot will take care of the rest through autoconfiguration.

By default spring or springboot configures the following message converters during startup:

> ```
> ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
> StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
> ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
> SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
> FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
> Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML
> MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON
> MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON
> AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds 
> RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds
> ```

Dependencies that you may need to add :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring Boot, the `jackson-databind` dependency comes in the `spring-boot-starter-json` module (which also is included in other spring boot started moduled, like `spring-boot-starter-web`).

If you specify the starter module in your dependencies, you will be able to write read/write json program with the jackson version which comes with Spring. The good practice to specify this dependency explicitly since the functionality might change with Spring update.

The code example with Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    return args -> {
        String john = objectMapper().writeValueAsString(new User("John", 43));

        System.out.println(john);
    };
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Update:
In Spring 5.1.* `org.springframework.spring-web` dependency, the Jackson is also provided and can be used as in the example above.

Comment: btw how to find out this dependency tree? Like you mentioned starter-json is included in starter-web etc? Where did you find this information? Is there a website that prints this in a tree format or is there a plugin?

Comment: I'm using Maven's dependency:tree command to see all the included dependencies. If you use Intellij products, you could go to 'Maven' -> 'Show dependencies' in your pom.xml context menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply inject ObjectMapper which already defined in Spring via @Autowired or constructor in the configuration. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

@Bean
public SomeService someService(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  return new SomeService(objectMapper);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ObjectMapper, first of all add jackson kotlin support by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you can create kotlin jackson mapper instance anywhere in your project like this

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper

val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
```

For serialization:

```
val serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(OBJECT)
```

For deserialization:

```
mapper.readValue(json)
```

You can find more information from this [topic](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-kotlin).